# I'm trying to get an image to appear after a clicked image fades out

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get an image to appear after a clicked image fades out. For some reason it isn't working. Anyone know what's wrong?

JSfiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/1ahwhqdm/1/

Html:-

```
<img id="picture" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2013/11/11/article-2500617-007F32C500000258-970_306x423.jpg">
```

Javascript:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var imageName = ["http://www.coloring-painting-pages.com/c-pics/Donald-Duck.jpg", "http://www.thinksnaps.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/RTGRX9rTL.jpeg", "http://www.search-best-cartoon.com/cartoon-mouse/cartoon-mouse-and-cheese-04.jpg"];
    var indexNum = 0;
    $("#picture").click(function () {
        $("#picture").fadeOut(300, function () {
            $("#picture").attr("src", imageName[0]);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
 $("#picture").attr("src", imageName[0]).fadeIn(200);
```

Instead of

```
$("#picture").attr("src", imageName[0]);
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/1ahwhqdm/2/)

Hope It helps you

Comment: How come the image did not just pop up though? I told it to fade out and then right after to bring up another picture. What you put does work but i am  just trying to understand why it did not work.

Comment: Hey when we using `fadeOut` the element is hide, now if we want to show again that element need to implement `fadeIn`.

Answer (score 0):

You faded out the picture. Just 'cause you change the `src` doesn't mean it'll fade back in.
Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var imageName = ["http://www.coloring-painting-pages.com/c-pics/Donald-Duck.jpg", "http://www.thinksnaps.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/RTGRX9rTL.jpeg", "http://www.search-best-cartoon.com/cartoon-mouse/cartoon-mouse-and-cheese-04.jpg"];
    var indexNum = 0;
    $("#picture").click(function () {
        $("#picture").fadeOut(300, function () {
            $("#picture").attr("src", imageName[0]);
        }).delay(100).fadeIn(300); //Have to fade back in.
    });
});
```